# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 during linking

Tags: c, cmake, gnu-make

I am compiling a pretty large C and C++ program called APBS using Apple clang version 12.0.5.  When make gets to a linker step to link the headers with the main source `routines.c` it gives this error below.  it has to be something easy

```
[ 30%] Linking C shared library ../lib/libapbs_routines.dylib
+ cd /Users/brian/tools/apbs/build/src
+ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.22.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/apbs_routines.dir/link.txt --verbose=
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_Vacc_atomSASA", referenced from:
      _initAPOL in routines.c.o
  "_Vacc_atomSurf", referenced from:
      _forceAPOL in routines.c.o
  "_Vacc_atomdSASA", referenced from:
      _forceAPOL in routines.c.o
  "_Vacc_atomdSAV", referenced from:
      _forceAPOL in routines.c.o
  "_Vacc_ctor", referenced from:
      _initAPOL in routines.c.o
  "_Vacc_dtor", referenced from:
      _initAPOL in routines.c.o
  "_Vacc_totalSASA", referenced from:
      _initAPOL in routines.c.o
...
 "_Vgrid_ctor", referenced from:
      _loadDielMaps in routines.c.o
      _loadKappaMaps in routines.c.o
      _loadPotMaps in routines.c.o
      _loadChargeMaps in routines.c.o
      _writedataMG in routines.c.o
  "_Vgrid_dtor", referenced from:
      _killDielMaps in routines.c.o
      _killKappaMaps in routines.c.o
      _killPotMaps in routines.c.o
      _killChargeMaps in routines.c.o
      _writedataMG in routines.c.o
  "_Vgrid_readDX", referenced from:
      _loadDielMaps in routines.c.o
      _loadKappaMaps in routines.c.o
      _loadPotMaps in routines.c.o
      _loadChargeMaps in routines.c.o
...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

here is the tree for the src but they are not getting built in the build/src where the headers that define these functions are in src/fem, src/generic

```
/Users/brian/tools/apbs/src
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── apbs.h
├── fem
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── vcsm.c
│   ├── vcsm.h
│   ├── vfetk.c
│   ├── vfetk.h
│   ├── vpee.c
│   └── vpee.h
├── generic
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── apolparm.c
│   ├── apolparm.h
│   ├── bemparm.c
│   ├── bemparm.h
│   ├── femparm.c
│   ├── femparm.h
│   ├── geoflowparm.c
│   ├── geoflowparm.h
│   ├── mgparm.c
│   ├── mgparm.h
│   ├── nosh.c
│   ├── nosh.h
│   ├── pbamparm.c
│   ├── pbamparm.h
│   ├── pbeparm.c
│   ├── pbeparm.h
│   ├── pbsamparm.c
│   ├── pbsamparm.h
│   ├── vacc.c
│   ├── vacc.h
│   ├── valist.c
│   ├── valist.h
│   ├── vatom.c
│   ├── vatom.h
│   ├── vcap.c
│   ├── vcap.h
│   ├── vclist.c
│   ├── vclist.h
│   ├── vgreen.c
│   ├── vgreen.h
│   ├── vhal.h
│   ├── vmatrix.h
│   ├── vparam.c
│   ├── vparam.h
│   ├── vpbe.c
│   ├── vpbe.h
│   ├── vstring.c
│   ├── vstring.h
│   └── vunit.h
├── main.c
├── mg
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── vgrid.c
│   ├── vgrid.h
│   ├── vmgrid.c
│   ├── vmgrid.h
│   ├── vopot.c
│   ├── vopot.h
│   ├── vpmg.c
│   ├── vpmg.h
│   ├── vpmgp.c
│   └── vpmgp.h
├── pmgc
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── PMG-README.txt
│   ├── README.txt
│   ├── buildAd.c
│   ├── buildAd.h
│   ├── buildBd.c
│   ├── buildBd.h
│   ├── buildGd.c
│   ├── buildGd.h
│   ├── buildPd.c
│   ├── buildPd.h
│   ├── cgd.c
│   ├── cgd.h
│   ├── gsd.c
│   ├── gsd.h
│   ├── matvecd.c
│   ├── matvecd.h
│   ├── mgcsd.c
│   ├── mgcsd.h
│   ├── mgdrvd.c
│   ├── mgdrvd.h
│   ├── mgfasd.c
│   ├── mgfasd.h
│   ├── mgsubd.c
│   ├── mgsubd.h
│   ├── mikpckd.c
│   ├── mikpckd.h
│   ├── mlinpckd.c
│   ├── mlinpckd.h
│   ├── mypdec.c
│   ├── mypdec.h
│   ├── newdrvd.c
│   ├── newdrvd.h
│   ├── newtond.c
│   ├── newtond.h
│   ├── powerd.c
│   ├── powerd.h
│   ├── smoothd.c
│   └── smoothd.h
├── routines.c
└── routines.h
```

and the src/CMakeLists.txt adds these directories, seems super simple to solve but I am just learning

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

macro(add_items TYPE)

    # Make sure the TYPE argument is valid
    set(ALLOWABLE_TYPES SOURCES EXTERNAL_HEADERS INTERNAL_HEADERS)
    list(FIND ALLOWABLE_TYPES ${TYPE} VALID_TYPE)
    if(VALID_TYPE EQUAL -1)
        message(
            FATAL_ERROR
            "Passed an invalid type to add_items macro.  "
            "Must be one of SOURCES, EXTERNAL_HEADERS, or INTERNAL_HEADERS.  "
            "Was ${TYPE}"
        )
    endif()

    # The items to add will be any additional parameters beyond TYPE
    set(ITEMS ${ARGN})

    # Add each item successively to the appropriately typed list
    foreach(ITEM ${ITEMS})
        list(APPEND ${TYPE} "${ITEM}")
    endforeach()

endmacro()

macro(add_sublibrary LIBRARY)
    set(LIBRARY_NAME "apbs_${LIBRARY}")
    set(LIBRARY_DEPENDENCIES ${APBS_LIBS} ${ARGN})
    message(STATUS "Adding ${LIBRARY_NAME}")
    message(STATUS "With source files ${SOURCES}")
    message(STATUS "With external header files ${EXTERNAL_HEADERS}")
    message(STATUS "With internal header files ${INTERNAL_HEADERS}")
    message(STATUS "With library dependencies ${LIBRARY_DEPENDENCIES}")
    add_library(${LIBRARY_NAME} ${SOURCES} ${EXTERNAL_HEADERS} ${INTERNAL_HEADERS})
    target_link_libraries(${LIBRARY_NAME} ${LIBRARY_DEPENDENCIES})
    #add_dependencies(${LIBRARY_NAME} ${LIBRARY_DEPENDENCIES})
    INSTALL(FILES ${EXTERNAL_HEADERS} DESTINATION ${HEADER_INSTALL_PATH}/${LIBRARY})
    INSTALL(TARGETS ${LIBRARY_NAME} DESTINATION ${LIBRARY_INSTALL_PATH})
    list(APPEND APBS_INTERNAL_LIBS ${LIBRARY_NAME})
    set(APBS_INTERNAL_LIBS ${APBS_INTERNAL_LIBS} PARENT_SCOPE)
    message(STATUS "Added ${LIBRARY_NAME}")
endmacro()

add_subdirectory(generic)
add_subdirectory(pmgc)
add_subdirectory(mg)

if(ENABLE_FETK)
   add_subdirectory(fem)
endif(ENABLE_FETK)

add_items(SOURCES routines.c)
add_sublibrary(routines)

message(STATUS "External Headers: ${EXTERNAL_HEADERS}")

#add_executable(apbs main.c routines.c)
add_executable(apbs main.c apbs.h routines.c routines.h)
message(STATUS " ")
message(STATUS "APBS Libraries: ${APBS_LIBS}")
message(STATUS "Internal Libraries: ${APBS_INTERNAL_LIBS}")
message(STATUS " ")

#add_dependencies(apbs ${BEM_LIB})
#target_include_directories(apbs PRIVATE apbs.h routines.h)
target_link_libraries(apbs ${APBS_LIBS} ${APBS_INTERNAL_LIBS} ${APBS_LIBS})
#add_dependencies(apbs ${APBS_LIBS} ${APBS_INTERNAL_LIBS} ${APBS_LIBS})

#configure_file(
#    ${APBS_ROOT}/src/.config/apbscfg.h.in
#    ${APBS_BUILD}/src/apbscfg.h
#    )

if(ENABLE_iAPBS)
#    ADD_LIBRARY(apbs_routines routines.c routines.h)
#    INSTALL(TARGETS apbs_routines DESTINATION ${LIBRARY_INSTALL_PATH})
    INSTALL(FILES ${APBS_BUILD}/src/apbscfg.h DESTINATION ${HEADER_INSTALL_PATH})
endif()


################################################################################
#  We have to fix the dynamically linked libraries 
################################################################################
if(APPLE)
  set(HARDPATH "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/fetk/lib")
  foreach (hardlib ${APBS_LIBS})
    set(HARDNAME "lib${hardlib}.1.dylib")
    message(STATUS "#############################################################")
    message(STATUS "#############################################################")
    message(STATUS "#############################################################")
    message(STATUS "#############################################################")
    message(STATUS "** Change path for hardlib - ${hardlib}")
    message(STATUS "COMMAND install_name_tool -change ${HARDPATH}/${HARDNAME} @executable_path/../lib/${HARDNAME} ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin/apbs")
    message(STATUS "#############################################################")
    add_custom_command(TARGET apbs POST_BUILD
                       COMMAND install_name_tool -change ${HARDPATH}/${HARDNAME} @executable_path/../lib/${HARDNAME} ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin/apbs
    )
  endforeach()
endif()

INSTALL(FILES apbs.h routines.h DESTINATION ${HEADER_INSTALL_PATH})
INSTALL(TARGETS apbs DESTINATION ${EXECUTABLE_INSTALL_PATH})
```

Sorry also here is the `CMakeFiles/apbs_routines.dir/link.txt`

```
/usr/bin/gcc  -fPIC -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -o ../lib/libapbs_routines.dylib -install_name @rpath/libapbs_routines.dylib CMakeFiles/apbs_routines.dir/routines.c.o   -L/Users/brian/tools/apbs/build/fetk/lib  -L/Users/brian/tools/apbs/build/geoflow-prefix/src/geoflow-build/lib  -Wl,-rpath,/Users/brian/tools/apbs/build/fetk/lib -Wl,-rpath,/Users/brian/tools/apbs/build/geoflow-prefix/src/geoflow-build/lib -lm -lstdc++ -lmaloc -lamd -lpunc -lmc -lgamer -lsuperlu -lumfpack -lblas -lvf2c -ltetgen -ltriangle -lreadline -ltermcap /usr/local/lib/libumfpack.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/openblas/0.3.19/lib/libopenblas.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/superlu/5.2.2_1/lib/libsuperlu.dylib -lGeometricFlowLib -Xclang -fopenmp
```

Comment: ***using Apple clang version 12.0.5.*** why do you have gcc command when you are using clang?

Comment: sorry Apple just uses that:
`/usr/bin/gcc -v`

`Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin`

Comment: @kiner_shah gcc is symbolic link to clang by default when Apple Clang is installed on MacOS

Comment: BTW is your src/CMakeLists.txt the whole file? Where are you creating the executable, linking libraries/including headers?

Comment: @kiner_shah it's a long(ish) file I just added it

Comment: You are calling add_sublibrary(routines) which is a macro and inside that macro there is EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, etc. which doesn't seem to be initialized before. Can you check the CMake output, if the values are properly output?

Comment: Is this that software: https://github.com/Electrostatics/apbs ?

Comment: Yup, looks like they are actively updating, I'm just looking to learn how to make larger projects

Comment: @kiner_shah ah yes it says `-- External Headers:     ` is blank.  I can look how to fix somewhere online.  Again just learning.  It's weird because there is also a `apbs/build/src/CMakeFiles/apbs_routines.dir/routines.c.o.d` file that has each one of these files under `src/CMakeFiles/apbs_routines.dir/routines.c.o: \ `

Comment: Well it's def an Apple Clang issue.  gcc from homebrew is working.  Apple is def making too many changes too quickly.  They should have been stearing the titanic :(.  Do you think it's worth opening issue at Apple?